# Object defined error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA macro which compares two spreadsheets and updates the other if they are different and for some reason it is giving me an object defined error at the if statement in the second for loop.  I am not sure why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()
  Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, N As Long, C As Long
  Dim rng1Row As Range
  Dim rng2Row As Range


  N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
  Set rng1 = Sheet1.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
  Set rng2 = Sheet2.Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)


For i = 2 To rng1.Rows.Count
    Set rng1Row = rng1.Cells(R, 1).EntireRow
    Set rng2Row = rng2.Cells(R, 1).EntireRow
        For j = 1 To rng1.Columns.Count
           If rng1Row.Cells(i, j).Value <> rng2Row.Cells(R, C).Value Then
                rng1Row.Cells(i, j).Value.Copy
                Sheet2.Activate
                rng2Row.Cells(i, j).Paste
             Else
                'Do something if they ARE equal
            End If
        Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: R and C have no values in `rng2Row.Cells(R, C).Value`

Comment: Could you please show which line is causing the issue? Also please tell what have you tried so far.

Comment: yeah indeed what does R represent when you set the rngrows?

Answer (score 0):

Please check couple of below points and hope this will help you to resolve the error.

1. Variables R and C has not be initialized to any default value. While R has not even declared.
2. As you are incrementing variables `i` and `j` in For Loop, `R` and `C` are never getting incremented and as a result you will be checking each new cell of sheet1 with same cell of sheet2. I don't know whether you intend to do that.